# Choosing a unique answer from Pareto set in multi objective optimization

Tags: optimization

In multi-objective optimization, we do the optimization process and at the end, we end up having a set of non-dominated answers. My question is about the existing methods for choosing a unique answer from this Pareto set. In many physical problems, we need to know one answer which is best answer. I know there is no unique "best" in multi-objective, but I mean "best" by some metrics that we define and these metrics are related to our specific problem.
I assume there should be some methods, algorithms for this. Any ideas/ references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would think that the classification of "best" heavily depends on the problem at hand or even on the person looking at the problem. So you should provide a lot more details about the concrete problem you are looking at.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DanielJunglas. In fact I want to get familiar with some existing ideas to find out how to define a metric for my problem. For instance, consider having two outputs Q1 and Q2 and we want to maximize both of them. Is it acceptable if we say that, among the non-dominated points, we choose the point which has highest value of Q1 and that single point is the answer to our specific problem?